# Как уменьшить размер используемой памяти?

Tags: java, android

Написал графическую игровую программу. Пока писал тестил на эмуляторах и на смартфоне. Всё работало хорошо. Потом решил попробовать на другом смартфоне - программа через небольшой промежуток времени вываливается. Посмотрел размер используемой памяти с помощью Profiler  в AndroidStudio. Получил такой результат для смартфона на котором программа идёт нормально (Доступное ОЗУ - 750MB, версия андроид 7.1.1):

> Total - 115MB; Java - 74MB; Native - 5,8MB; Graphics - 7,6MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 21,5 MB; Others - 5MB.

Все значения постоянные, кроме Java. Этот параметр растёт примерно до - 90MB. Потом сборщик мусора убирает всё лишнее и параметр (Java) снова опускается на начальное значение.

На другом смартфоне тоже всё работает(Доступное ОЗУ - 500MB, версия андроид - 10):

> Total - 161MB; Java - 13MB; Native - 100MB; Graphics - 9MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 34 MB; Others - 7MB.

При этом у него изменяется только параметр Native от 60 до 100MB

На 3-м смартфоне программа вываливается через 1-2 минуты игры. Данные из Profiler:

> Total - 166MB; Java - 81MB; Native - 11MB; Graphics - 35MB; Stack - 0,6MB; Code - 29 MB; Others - 5MB.

При этом у него изменяется только параметр Java от 70 до 80MB (примерно)
Выдаёт ошибку - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 576012 byte allocation with 45728 free bytes and 44KB until OOM

(Доступное ОЗУ - 400MB, версия андроид - 7.0)

Обратил внимание, что 3-й смартфон силней загружает параметр Graphics, имеет меньше свободного ОЗУ, и версия андроид - 7.0. Может ли это влиять на появление ошибки не пойму.

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема?

Добавляю LOG

```
2021-02-26 12:51:22,824 [6294715]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363961ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : installer 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363965ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : Command Dump 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,291 [6295182]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284363966ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : get process ids 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364116ms LOG_ERR [22751][22751] : Could not get package user id: run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364117ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364117ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromDump 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_BEG [22751][22751] : processing APK 
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:23,292 [6295183]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284364222ms TRC_END [22751][22751] :  
2021-02-26 12:51:25,216 [6297107]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - Install successfully finished in 2 s 382 ms.. App restart successful without requiring a re-install. 
2021-02-26 12:51:26,834 [6298725]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - startCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:52:04,874 [6336765]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:52:04,874 [6336765]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopAll() 
2021-02-26 12:52:19,115 [6351006]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2021-02-26 12:52:19,645 [6351536]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appRegistry took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,487 [6456378]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - About to execute Gradle tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,503 [6456394]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,519 [6456410]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Build command line options: [-Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.1.1, -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Ura\AppData\Local\Temp\1614333244503-0, -Pandroid.injected.build.api=24, -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi, -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi] 
2021-02-26 12:54:04,519 [6456410]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=10.4.1.1 -Pandroid.injected.attribution.file.location=C:\Users\Ura\AppData\Local\Temp\1614333244503-0 -Pandroid.injected.build.api=24 -Pandroid.injected.build.density=xxhdpi -Pandroid.injected.build.abi=armeabi-v7a,armeabi 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,266 [6457157]   INFO - ild.invoker.GradleBuildInvoker - Gradle build finished in 750 ms 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,267 [6457158]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Couldn't get post build models. 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,267 [6457158]   INFO - a.gradle.run.MakeBeforeRunTask - Gradle invocation complete, success = true 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,275 [6457166]   INFO - idea.run.AndroidProcessHandler - Adding device samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439 to monitor for launched app: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,278 [6457169]   INFO - notification.NotificationGroup - Notification group LaunchTaskRunner is already registered 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:48)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:28)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.<init>(NotificationGroup.kt:36)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup$Companion.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.kt:93)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup$Companion.toolWindowGroup$default(NotificationGroup.kt:92)
    at com.intellij.notification.NotificationGroup.toolWindowGroup(NotificationGroup.kt)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:183)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:932)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$null$3(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:166)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:627)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:153)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:233)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-02-26 12:54:05,279 [6457170]   INFO - ools.idea.run.tasks.DeployTask - Installing application: com.medinq.superlines 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : installer 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : Command Dump 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526413ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : get process ids 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526563ms LOG_ERR [23108][23108] : Could not get package user id: run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not permitted
 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526564ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526564ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : CmdCommand::GetApksFromDump 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_BEG [23108][23108] : processing APK 
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:05,717 [6457608]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - 284526651ms TRC_END [23108][23108] :  
2021-02-26 12:54:06,969 [6458860]   INFO - a.run.tasks.AbstractDeployTask - Install successfully finished in 1 s 689 ms.. App restart successful without requiring a re-install. 
2021-02-26 12:54:09,280 [6461171]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - startCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:54:49,324 [6501215]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopCapture("samsung-sm_a510f-3300376233021439") 
2021-02-26 12:54:49,324 [6501215]   INFO - run.AndroidLogcatOutputCapture - stopAll() 
2021-02-26 12:55:27,086 [6538977]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appBuiltInServerOptions took 15 ms, PropertiesComponent took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:55:27,117 [6539008]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project (name=SuperLines, containerState=ACTIVE, componentStore=C:\Users\Ura\AndroidStudioProjects\SuperLines) ProjectView took 16 ms 
2021-02-26 12:55:37,825 [6549716]   INFO - j.ide.actions.RevealFileAction - Exit code 1 
2021-02-26 12:55:38,340 [6550231]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving appExportableFileTemplateSettings took 16 ms
```

Comment: что тут гадать, нужно смотреть Log

Comment: @Style-7, добавил LOG. Но, к сожалению, понять в чём ошибка не могу